# Build a UCS-2 encoded HEX string from a Javascript default string encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, deno, ucs2

How to build a UCS-2 encoded HEX string from a Javascript "basic" string, but only using web api (browser or Deno) features ?

In other words, how to convert the following node code but for the browser ?

```js
message = "hello world "
const buf_le = Buffer.from(message, "ucs2"); // 'ucs2' is as same as 'utf16le'
let buf = Buffer.alloc(buf_le.length); // convert to utf16be (ucs2)
for (let i = 0; i < buf.length; i += 2)
  buf.writeUInt16BE(buf_le.readUInt16LE(i), i);
hex = buf.toString("hex");
```

It will be used to encode text to PDU for SMS sendings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution from [How to convert ArrayBuffer to and from String - Chrome Developers](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/how-to-convert-arraybuffer-to-and-from-string/) (usage of `var` updated to use `const` or `let`):

```js
function str2ab(str) {
  const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length * 2); // 2 bytes for each char
  const bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
  for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}
```

It uses a [`Uint16Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint16Array) as the view into the [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer). "The **`Uint16Array`** typed array represents an array of 16-bit unsigned integers in the platform byte order. If control over byte order is needed, use [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) instead."

To get a hex representation there are several options:

1. view the `buf` using a `Uint16Array` instance so that you don't need to concern yourself with your platform's byte order:

   ```js
   function uint16Array2hex(array) {
     return Array.from(array, (b) => b.toString(16).padStart(4, "0")).join("");
   }
   ```
2. update `str2ab` to use a `DataView` instead of `Uint16Array` so that you can write directly to network byte order (big endian):

   ```js
   function str2ab(str) {
     const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length * 2); // 2 bytes for each char
     const bufView = new DataView(buf);
     for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
       bufView.setUint16(2 * i, str.charCodeAt(i));
     }
     return buf;
   }

   function buf2hex(buf) {
     const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
     return Array.from(bufView, (b) => b.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")).join("");
   }
   ```
3. Keep `str2ab` as-is from Chrome Developers and then convert from platform endianness to big-endian by reading from the `buf` using `Uint16Array` and writing to a buffer using a `DataView` like seen above.

Comment: Thank you. Any reason why `bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i)` from str2ab does not produce utf-16be by default ? Does Javascript use internally LE for `new Uint16Array`?

Comment: Now that you mention you the endianness is probably system dependent... I will update this answer after I give it some more thought.

Comment: @nestarz I've updated my answer to account for platform endianness